# How can I use chart tooltip formatter in react-highcharts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-redux, react-highcharts

how can I use chart tooltip formatter?
I am using react wrapper for highcharts.
I have config like this:

```
const CHART_CONFIG = {
    ...
    tooltip:  
    {
        formatter: (tooltip) => {
            var s = '<b>' + this.x + '</b>';
            _.each(this.points, () => {
                s += '<br/>' + this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + 'm';
            });
            return s;
        },
        shared: true
    },
    ...
}
```

But I can't access chart scope using this keyword and also I can't get point from tooltip param.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've already encountered this problem. I've solved it by creating a function to format the tooltip, and applying default values to the data I wanted.

Here is [a live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-highcharts-tooltip-formatter?embed=1&file=index.js), with the code below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import ReactHighcharts from 'react-highcharts';
import './style.css';

class App extends Component {
  static formatTooltip(tooltip, x = this.x, points = this.points) {
    let s = `<b>${x}</b>`;
    points.forEach((point) =>
      s += `<br/>${point.series.name}: ${point.y}m`
    );

    return s;
  }

  static getConfig = () => ({
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    tooltip: {
      formatter: App.formatTooltip,
      shared: true,
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }, {
        data: [194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4]
    }],
  })

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ReactHighcharts config={App.getConfig())} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `this.props.navs` you are passing around? I logged it to the console before the render function and it's undefined?

Answer (score 12):

OP couldn't figure out how to access the scope of the chart using the `this` keyword. The simple answer is because OP was using a fat arrow function. Instead, try using a normal function as per this modified version of the OP's code:

```
const CHART_CONFIG = {
    ...
    tooltip:  
    {
        formatter() {   // Use a normal fn, not a fat arrow fn
            // Access properties using `this`
            // Return HTML string
        },
        shared: true
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is because arrow functions lose track of "this" and we have to use normal functions :) thank you

Comment: You are right way. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

here's another way that also helps you use React components as part of the tooltip itself.

```
const Item = ({name, value}) => <div> {name}: {value}</div>

const config = { 
  formatter(this) {
    const container = document.createElement("div");
    return this.points.map(point => {
      ReactDOM.render(
        <Item name={point.series.name} value={point.y}/>
      )
      return container.innerHTML
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts expects that tootlip fromatter will return an HTML string. When using react wrapper for Highcharts, it is possible to write a custom tooltip component with formatted data, then in the options when setting up formatter function you can use *ReactDOMServer's* `renderToString` method which will create HTML string from the given element.
Though renderToString is intended for server-side rendering  mainly, it can be used in browsers' environment without any problem.

```
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import CustomTooltip from './CustomTooltip';

const options = {
    tooltip: {
        formatter() {
            return ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<CustomTooltip {...this} />);
        },
    },
};
```

Answer (score -2):

I have created a tooltip switcher which can be used as a regular tooltip or as shared.

The `isTooltipShared` is a boolean prop that indicates if a tooltip is shared or not.

```
const options = {
    tooltip: {
              formatter: props.isTooltipShared ?
                function () {
                  let s = `<b> ${this.x} </b>`;
                  this.points.forEach((point) => {
                    s += `<br/> ${point.series.name} : ${point.y}`;
                  });
                  return s;
                } : function () {
                  return `${this.series.name} : <b> ${this.x} </b> - <b> ${this.y} </b>`;
                },
              shared: props.isTooltipShared,
            },
};
```

And used with,

```
<HighchartsReact
   highcharts={Highcharts}
   options={options}
/>
```